# Lightbox & map area

Tags: jquery, lightbox, area

I am trying to make a lightbox work off an image map. But when I execute this I get an error that the click event can not be found.  What am I missing?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('area.optSelectMe').click(function() {
     $("#span1").click();
  });
});
</script>

<script src="Scripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <map id="EnrollmentPageMap" name="EnrollmentPageMap" style="z-index: 10;">
            <area alt="Enroll Now" shape="rect" coords="0, 639, 363, 749" href="Enrollment.aspx" />
            <area alt="View 360" id="View360" class="optSelectMe" shape="rect" coords="806, 569, 1006, 633" href="#" />
        </map>
        <img src="images/EnrollmentPageBackground.jpg" usemap="#EnrollmentPageMap" alt="" />
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8687.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span1"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8688.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span2"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8699.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span3"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8689.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span4"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8690.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span5"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8691.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span6"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8692.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span7"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8693.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span8"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8694.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span9"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8695.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span10"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8696.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span11"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8697.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span12"></span></a>
        <a href="images/View360/MG_8698.JPG" rel="lightbox[View360]"><span id="span13"></span></a>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try adding `$(document).ready(function(){ .. your script here .. });` also don't forget to include `jQuery`

Comment: Still didn't work, I still get an error that the click event can't be found.

Comment: which click event? the first or the second?

Comment: Prototype and jQuery don't exactly work well with each other.  Both libraries use $, so that would explain why $(element).click() doesn't work.  Remove the Prototype script and replace it with jQuery.  Move your code to the bottom of the page and then see if that works.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica if that's the case you can also use [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Yeah, or you could wrap the function in such a way that $ is bound to only jQuery/ Prototype as well.  Moral of the story is that if he can't get his scripts to work, he shouldn't be attempting to use two conflicting libraries together at the same time.

Comment: That worked removing the Prototype. Thanks!